# I am struggling with a linear programming using python.

Tags: python

So below is the problem statement:
A car company produces 2 models, model A and model B. Long-term projections indicate an expected demand of at least 100 model A cars and 80 model B cars each day. Because of limitations on production capacity, no more than 200 model A cars and 170 model B cars can be made daily. To satisfy a shipping contract, a total of at least 200 cars much be shipped each day. If each model A car sold results in a $2000 loss, but each model B car produces a $5000 profit, how many of each type should be made daily to maximize net profits?

How can I solve it using python.

I am new to coding.

Also, what is the difference between linear regression and linear programming?

Comment: Check out the package `pulp` for linear programming.

Comment: As for the difference between linear regression/programming, the former is a statistical technique for estimation, the latter is a method for optimization.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service; please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you Joel for the clarification. I would keep in mind .

Comment: Theankyou Demetri for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Give this solution a shot:

```
modelA = -2000
modelB = 5000

maxProductionA = 200
maxProducitonB = 170

highestProfit = 0
numA = 0
numB = 0

for a in range(maxProductionA):
  for b in range(maxProducitonB):
    if a + b >= 200:
      total = (a * modelA + b * modelB)
      if(total > highestProfit):
        highestProfit = total
        numA = a
        numB = b
print("selling: ", numA, " model A cars and ", numB, " modelB cars would give a profit of: ", highestProfit)
```